# when you loop through results how do you know which record to delete

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

If I was looping through a number of results in a foreach and the list was as such -

```
-item 1
delete

-item 2
delete

-item 3
delete

-item 4
delete
```

If I want to delete the `item 3` record how can I find the correct id for that iteration for my query. Normally I would use a get request but that wouldn't work in this case.

Thanks

```
@foreach ($statuses as $status)
    <div class="media post-margin">
        <a class="pull-left" href="{{ route('profile.index', ['username' => $status->user->username]) }}">
            <img class="media-object" alt="{{ $status->user->getNameOrUsername() }}" src="{{ $status->user->getAvatarUrl() }}">
        </a>
        <div class="media-body">
            <h4 class="media-heading"><a href="{{ route('profile.index', ['username' => $status->user->username]) }}">{{ $status->user->getNameOrUsername() }}</a></h4>
            <span>{{ $status->created_at->diffForHumans() }}</span>
        </div>
            <p>{{ $status->body }}</p>
            <hr>
            <ul class="list-inline">
                    <li><a href="{{ route('status.like', ['statusId' => $status->id]) }}"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up fa-liked"></i> {{ $status->likes->count() }} {{ str_plural('like', $status->likes->count()) }}</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i> Comment</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-retweet"></i> Share</a></li>
                    @if ($status->user->id === Auth::user()->id)
                        <li id="remove"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Delete</li>
                    @endif
            </ul>
            <hr>
      </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Is the string `delete` part of the array? Please show us the output in a proper array format.

Comment: no its not, its  foreach outputting the relevant data were required, the delete is just an anchor tag with the text delete.

Comment: Please show us the foreach loop, I'm having a hard time understanding whether `-item` is the array key or if it's part of the array value.

Comment: @Epodax I _think_ OP is describing output badly. I'm guessing it's trying to say that the loop outputs the item name and there a delete link, or something. Just guessing.

Comment: Added real code example the delete can be seen in the list sorry for the confusion

Comment: What does your view have to do with deleting a record? Really not clear what the main issue is here

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass the record id to be deleted.

```
@foreach ($statuses as $status)
<div class="media post-margin">
    <a class="pull-left" href="{{ route('profile.index', ['username' => $status->user->username]) }}">
        <img class="media-object" alt="{{ $status->user->getNameOrUsername() }}" src="{{ $status->user->getAvatarUrl() }}">
    </a>
    <div class="media-body">
        <h4 class="media-heading"><a href="{{ route('profile.index', ['username' => $status->user->username]) }}">{{ $status->user->getNameOrUsername() }}</a></h4>
        <span>{{ $status->created_at->diffForHumans() }}</span>
    </div>
        <p>{{ $status->body }}</p>
        <hr>
        <ul class="list-inline">
                <li><a href="{{ route('status.like', ['statusId' => $status->id]) }}"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up fa-liked"></i> {{ $status->likes->count() }} {{ str_plural('like', $status->likes->count()) }}</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i> Comment</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-retweet"></i> Share</a></li>
                @if ($status->user->id === Auth::user()->id)
                    <li id="remove"><a href="{{route('status.delete',['statusId',$status -> id])}}"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Delete</li>
                @endif
        </ul>
        <hr>
  </div>
@endforeach
```

Routes

```
route::get('/delete/{$id}',['as' =>'status.delete' , 'uses' => 'YourController@delete']);
```

Controller

```
public function delete($id){
    Model::destroy($id); // 
}
```

Hope this help.